# Why MismatchSenderId when I send to token recieved not from localhost?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I send POST via Postman to fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send and if I send with token which recieved from localhost - all work good. But on production I recieve token, but can't send messages, I recive error MismatchSenderId

Comment: What code did you use?

Comment: For sending or for recieving?